# Where do I place parenthetical citations?

Tags: grammar

Do I place it inside the sentence like this:

> Family engagement is crucial to developing children’s emergent literacy skills because children who are raised in homes that promote literacy do better in school and they grow up to be better readers (Groski, n.d).

Or outside the sentence like this:

> Family engagement is crucial to developing children’s emergent literacy skills because children who are raised in homes that promote literacy do better in school and they grow up to be better readers. (Groski, n.d)

Comment: The style guide that specifies how your citations work. APA, which has author-comma-date-in-round-brackets (such as you're using), specifies the former example as correct.

Comment: Citations are on-topic on Writers. They are not part of the English language.